# C# and Locations on Forms

Tags: c#, .net, mouseevent

I'm trying to have a contextmenustrip object show up on the coordinates that a right click occurs on a particular form object.  I hooked into the forms CellMouseClick event and I can receive X,Y values for the event, but they seem to be relative to that particular control.  For example, if I use contextmenu.Show(e.X, e.Y), it will show in the top hand corner of the screen, as opposed to where the mouse is on that form.

How can I accomplish what I am looking to do?  If it helps, the form control I'm hooking into is DataGridView.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The DataGridView has a [ContextMenu](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.contextmenu.aspx) property that you can use for this.

Answer (score 2):

I would just set the [ContextMenuStrip property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.contextmenustrip(VS.80).aspx) of the DataGridView to your ContextMenuStrip, then it will always appear where your right-click on the grid.

You can set this in code as well as in the Properties window of the designer.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code:

```
ContextMenuStrip myMenuStrip = new ContextMenuStrip();
myMenuStrip.Show(myDataGrid , new Point(0 , 0));
```

and for a ContextMenu:

```
ContextMenu myMenu = new ContextMenu();
myMenu.Show(myDataGrid , new Point(e.X , e.Y));
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to check for left and top properties

```
x + control.left
y + control.top
```